# Installed Android Studio, can I use command line tools (lint adb etc) without downloading the SDK separately?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-lint

I just installed Android Studio, it took a bit of time and I saw it downloading the SDK during the installation process. So, I guess Android Studio somehow contains the SDK.

Now, Android Studio is OK but for my scripts I also need command line tools such as `lint`, `mksdcard`, `adb`, `fastboot`. In a normal SDK, these typically reside in `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` and `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`.

PROBLEM: I can't find these command line tools within the Android Studio folder. Zero result for:

```
find android-studio -type f -name lint
find android-studio -name sdk
```

Is there any better solution than downloading the SDK again? (This takes bandwidth, disk space, and time to upgrade everything once in a while)

*Android Studio 1.5.1 on Ubuntu 2015.10*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Android Studio setup includes the SDK. It includes most of the required stuff. If you need additional things you can launch the Stand Alone SDK manager from settings and download what ever additional things you need.

Open `File -> Settings` and select `Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK`, you will get this window:

[image: Android Studio settings: Android SDK]

Take note of the content of the value of the `Android SDK Location` field. Tools like adb, lint, etc are all found within this directory.